# implement notification dropdown for inbox messages using reactjs

Tags: spring, reactjs, socket.io

I need to imeplement notification badge in navbar similar to stackoverflow where it shows the number if you get any notificaiton.

Similar to this i need to display number as soon as the task progress which initiated from the web app has completed. For this iam using java spring for backend service.

Do I need to call the API frequently to verify the status or is there any better way to implement sth like the socket with spring.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: iam trying with PUSHER but its a third party plugin. @Paul Mcloughlin

Comment: Helpful reading: https://moduscreate.com/blog/fast-polling-vs-websockets-2/